# How to Have Function Definition and Subquery in With Clause of Oracle Select Statement?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I know the right syntax for having a function definition in the `WITH` clause. I know the right syntax for having a subquery in the `WITH` clause. But I have been unable to find an example of having a subquery ***and*** a function definition in the `WITH` clause of a `SELECT` statement.

If I have:

```
with totals as ( select colum_name from some_table )
select sum(column_name) from totals;
```

How do I add a function definition in the `WITH` clause?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do that? Did you get any errors? Let us know what is that you were trying to accomplish with some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't find much/anything about this from Oracle, I don't think it is a good idea to use it. Anyway, this works in 18.1:

`WITH 
  FUNCTION with_plus(p IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN p + 1;
    END;
  FUNCTION with_min(p IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN p - 1;
    END;
  qry1 AS (
    SELECT with_plus(10) plus
      FROM DUAL
  ),
  qry2 AS (
    SELECT plus, with_min(10) min
      FROM qry1
  )
SELECT *
  FROM qry2
;
/`

So don't forget the slash / at the end.

If you ever find out how to put this whole block in a subquery, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any such restriction. However, I suspect that your problem has to do with column aliasing. Here's what worked for me:

```
with totals as (select sum(column_name) c1 from some_table)
select c1 from totals;
```

Oracle might have complained because you were trying to do something like:

```
with totals as (select sum(column_name) from some_table)
select sum(column_name) from totals;
```

Unfortunately, this is a consequence of name resolution. The subquery's column will get named "sum(column_name)". Since sum is a function, there's no way to reference that column name without Oracle thinking you're referencing the function. You have to give it another name in order to reference it anywhere else.

Edit: It seems that you want to define a function as if you would a view subquery. I don't think anything like this is possible. View subqueries really only perform textual substitution.

PL/SQL functions require a whole different parser, name resolution, compilation process, etc. Having them work in queries alone is hard enough.

Sorry to say, but you'd have to define your packages/procedures/functions normally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it seems that I was not clear in what I posted originally. I updated my question to clarify that I meant "function definition" and not simply using a function.

Comment: @kurzweil4 I think I got what you mean. Sorry to say, it's not possible.